Either incorrect spacing or incorrect size using matplotlib shared y axis and aspect equal
Context
I'm trying to display some timing data of differing algorithms which depend on some input size and another parameter. The goal is to have n plots showing the various algorithms and one summary plot.
the algorithm plots have Parameter to Execution Time axes and different lines for each input size, whilst the summary plot shows the Input size to Minimal Execution Time (parameter selected optimally).
Problem
For this I have the following code
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patheffects as pe

data = {
    "Case1": {
        10: ([10,20,30], [ 100, 20, 80 ]),
        1000: ([10,20,30], [ 200, 40, 100 ]),
    },

    "Case2": {
        10: ([10,20,30], [ 50, 60, 70 ]),
        1000: ([10,20,30], [ 100, 200, 300 ]),
    }
}

minimum_data = {
    "Case1": ([10,1000],[20, 40]),
    "Case2": ([10,1000],[50, 100])
}

minimum = 10
maximum = 400

plot_count = 2 + 1

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, plot_count,  figsize=(6*plot_count, 6), sharey=True)
*individual_plots, group_plot = axs

for ax, ( category, grouped ) in zip( individual_plots, data.items() ):
    for group, datum in grouped.items():
        ax.loglog(datum[0], datum[1])
        ax.text(datum[0][0], datum[1][0], f'size {group}', path_effects=[pe.withStroke(linewidth=4, foreground="white")])
        ax.set_aspect("equal", adjustable="box")
        ax.set_xlabel("parameter")
        ax.set_ylabel("total")
        ax.set_title(category)
        ax.set_ylim([minimum,maximum])

for category, data in minimum_data.items():
    group_plot.loglog(data[0], data[1], label=category)

group_plot.set_aspect("equal", adjustable="box")
group_plot.set_xlabel("size")
group_plot.set_ylabel("total")
group_plot.set_title("minimal totals")
group_plot.set_ylim([minimum,maximum])


fig.legend(
    title="categories",
    loc='outside center right'
)
plt.show()

Which produces something along the lines of

Where the subplots are too far apart and the shared y axis does not seem to be working.
Stretching the figure "fixes" the shared y axis, but makes the spacing worse.

Conversly, shrinking the image does the opposite.

Question
How would I keep the shared y Axis and have the margins between the different plots be identical? (Also working for more than 3 total plots)

It's working as intended, but your third ax x-axis is roughly 3 times wider than the first two. You can use plt.subplots(..., width_ratios=[1, 1, 3]), whose ratios can be computed automatically.
